# issue with handling json data from server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have an problem with handling data come from server , please see the code bellow :

php

```
echo json_encode(array("toshow"=>"<span class='text'><img src='greencheck.png'/>"));
```

javascript

```
$('#data').ajaxForm({
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.error == 1){
                        $('#preview').html("<span class='text'><img src='close.png'/>"+data.filename+" File exsist ..</span>");
                    }else{

                         $('.first').after(data.toshow);
                    }
                }
                }).submit();
```

problem is when i send data from the server as {'data'=>someData} , i have no problem .. when i send any html tags such as `{'data'=>"<span>some data</span>"}` success function in javascript is not processing anything so success = fails ..

case 1 : sending json data from the server example , {'error'=>1,'msg'=>file exists} , in this case every thing is ok .
[image]

case 2 : sending json data from the server example ,{'toshow'=>linkdatta...etc} , so in case of adding any html tag in json problem start so success function not working at all

[image]

Comment: nothing happen as i told you in case send any html tag inside my json am not getting in success function

Comment: can u see the errors from error console ?

Comment: What about properly closing your span tag ? If still not working, please add proper infomations : output of Console.log(data), and the response of your Ajax request (using F12 with Chrome or Firebug with Firefox).

Comment: ok , actually i have tried send data with out close tag , same problem , i think problem with < > as well ,, i have update post

Comment: ok its working am not sure what was the problem :)

Comment: i just add header('Content-type: application/json'); in server side work 100 % ... thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php file set content-type to json:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(.........);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data){
   var temp = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    if(temp.error == 1){

   }
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: am not getting inside success function at all when am sending html tag inside json data ...

Comment: inspect with firebug and check ajax request is working or not

Comment: ajax request working 100% every thing ok , problem is only with json data come from the server

Comment: I didn't find any `error` index in this array echo json_encode(array("toshow"=>"<span class='text'><img src='greencheck.png'/>"));

Comment: echo json_encode(array("toshow"=>"<span class='text'><img src='greencheck.png'/>","error"=>1));  change like this